# Put R-generated figure side-by-side with text in Quarto

Tags: r, figure, quarto

I have a quarto book where I want to include an R-generated figure using the following code:

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Histogram of Height",out.width='50%',fig.align='right',fig.asp=1}
df <- data.frame(
ClassInterval = c("59.5-62.5", "62.5-65.5", "65.5-68.5", "68.5-71.5", "71.5-74.5"),
Frequency = c(5, 18, 42, 27, 8)
)
with(df, barplot(height = Frequency / sum(Frequency), names.arg = ClassInterval, 
                 space = 0,
                 xlab = "Height",
                 ylab = "Frequency",
                 main = "Histogram of Height",
                 ylim = c(0, 0.45),
                 cex.names=0.8,
                 col = 'darkblue',
                 density=20))

box(col = 'black')
```
````

the resulting page looks like this:

[image: Result]

As you can see, the image caption does not align to the right along with the image, and there is an empty space to the left of the image, which should ideally be filled with text. The result I would like to have is this:

[image: Ideal]

with the area to the left of the figure filled with text. Does anyone have an idea as to how to achieve this? Thank you very much in advance.